# Proof that no Fermat number is can be expressed as $n^3$ where n is an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was given the above question by my lecturer as something to think about over the course of the summer. I realize that all Fermat numbers are odd, but since $n^3$ can be both even and odd I'm not sure that this helps. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Mau5

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$$2^{2^m}+1=n^3\implies2^{2^m}=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$$

Comment: And $n^2+n+1$ is always odd.

Comment: Many thanks for this, can you then argue that since $(n^2 + n +1)$ is always odd and the right hand side is always powers of $2$ which is always even, then no such relationship can be found? (I.e. proof by induction)?

Comment: @Mau5ter Yes, but you mean proof by contradiction, not induction.

Comment: @Mau5ter You need argue further, since even numbers can have odd divisors, e.g. $6.\ \ $

Comment: Should the $n^{3}$ be, say, $k^{3}$

Comment: @mlchristians Why?  The exponent on the left is $m$, not $n$.

Comment: My eyes didn't see that. Sorry. Nice proof.